# Why is my calculator for the binomial coefficient not working?

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code. I want to calculate all binomial coefficient to a certain row. It prints when I write 4:
1  /n 1  1 /n 4  2  1 /n 36  12  3  1.   But that is not right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int binominal(int n,int k){
            int a= 1;
            int b =1;
            int c =1;
            for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
                a= a*i;
            }
            for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
                b= b*i;
            }
            for(int i=1;i<=n-k;i++){
                c= c*i;
            }
            return a/(b*c);

}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{  int row = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(int j=0;j<row;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<=j;i++){
                printf(" %d ",binominal(i,j));
            } printf("\n");

     }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show an example of input along with expected vs actual output. Also your code does not compile. Please post your _actual_ code. And _"printing half the numbers the job"_ is not meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments in the call to `binomial` are reversed.  Instead of `binomial(i,j)`, you want `binomial(j,i)`.  The first argument is the row, and the second argument is the column.

There's also an extra `}` after the loop in `main`, probably introduced when pasting the code.

Here's a working version of `main`:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int row = atoi(argv[1]);

    for(int j=0;j<row;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<=j;i++){
            printf(" %d ",binominal(j,i));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's an output sample from the corrected version:

```
% binomial 6
 1 
 1  1 
 1  2  1 
 1  3  3  1 
 1  4  6  4  1 
 1  5  10  10  5  1 
%
```

Comment: The problem remains.

Comment: @Hector234 I ran it myself and got the expected output (Pascal's Triangle).  You must  have copied it wrong?  Just try pasting the entire version of `main` that I posted.  I promise it works.  Make sure you pass a command-line argument (e.g. 3).

Comment: @Hector234 Also, make sure you recompile it before testing the changes.  I just added sample output so you can see what you should get if you successfully replace your `main` with my version.

Comment: @Hector234 (1) Make sure you apply the changes correctly.  Replace your `main` with the one in the post, leaving everything else untouched, and (2) Make sure you recompile it before trying it again.  The bug is fixed, and it works (see the sample output I added to my post).  I suspect you forgot to recompile, or mistyped the name of the output file when compiling.